# bitbucket cloud no longer able to show files / commits

Tags: bitbucket

I am having a lot of stability issues using bitbucket cloud. I am looking at error messages that it's having trouble showing folders/files/commits, pretty much everything is falling apart.

I [opened a ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-14346) which literally gets no response at all.

I am on the verge of moving away from bitbucket (and if that's the case, dropping everything from atlassian I guess). My last resort is to check here if people recognize the problem.

I am seeing errors like:

[image]

[image]

Do people recognize this? Are there known solutions? I've read several (dated) topics that it had to do with some beta features and that disabling them in labs would solve the problem. I guess these features are out of beta because they are no longer listed as such. I have all other beta features disabled, it doesn't make a difference.

Should I give up are be patient? Anybody ?